# flip/roll text around horizontal axis?

Tags: modeling, text-object

I mean something like [image]

I saw an animation, in which every text has multi-layers, and every layer rolls to a cylinder at different speed

thanks

Comment: please post a link to animation that shows what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You may have luck looking into the Curve modifier.  You can make a curve with flat and coiled shape keys. Then you can add a curve modifier to your text mesh and animate the transition between the two shape keys.